# Show just row dendrogram from Seaborn ClusterMap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm currently creating a ClusterMap using seaborn, via the following simple code:

```
graph = seaborn.clustermap(df, method='ward', row_colors=row_colors, col_cluster=False, dendrogram_ratio=0.15)
```

I'd like to show/plot *just* the dendrogram related to the rows, and not print the entire clustermap matrix. Is there a way to do this? Apparently you can extract the linkage via:

```
dgram = graph.dendrogram_row.dendrogram
row_linkage = graph.dendrogram_row.linkage
```

But I'm not sure how to plot just these data. I'm aware that one can use the `scipy` approach to making dendrograms, but the functionality around creating `row_colors` doesn't appear accessible via just matplotlib.

Comment: Dendrogram plotting is actually built into scipy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html